# Java - Can compile all files in a directory at once, but not individually

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have about 10 .java files in a directory. There is no problem compiling all of them when I run

```
javac *.java
```

but when I try to compile an individual file, I get several "cannot find symbol" errors.  All of the referenced files are in the same directory, and I do not have any classes declared in a specific package.

Comment: Why do you think that happens?

Comment: what environment are you using? did you compile it using command line? you can't compile it piece by piece.

Comment: Ok, I fixed this by setting my classpath to ".", which sets the classpath to the current directory.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `class` files in your `classpath`, then it would work. But the compiler can't find symbols in `java` files, unless it is compiling them. Thus, simultaneously compiling all the related files makes the compiler find all the symbols; but one by one, it is missing both the sources (because they're not on command line) and the compiled classes (because they're not in the classpath), and you get your error.